# Data encryption on VPS

Tags: vps, encryption, disk-encryption

I know there is no way to completely secure a running system, however I'd like to do do what ever is possible.

I'm not sure how to phrase the question, but basically, I'd like to secure the data on the system, so noone would be able to access it.

- Is it possible to secure running processes in memory ?
- Assuming the VPS owner can easily gain root or access to the filesystem (by connecting the drive to another running system), what are my options to secure my data ?

Comment: I don't know of a way to encrypt a system on the fly. On the other hand, if you can't trust your VPS host to do their job with honesty and integrity, then perhaps you need to find another host. That or rent a cage in a local colo facility and run your own services.

Comment: The problem isn't with trusting specific VPS, but the the idea of hosting server with sensitive data where others have physical access to the machine, and which at some point be accessed by unwanted entities. This is why a colo'd cage wouldn't help either unless the system was encrypted.

Comment: In a typical colo, you have either a lockable cage or lockable rack. Even *if*  you're running a VPS with encrypted filesystems, all of the in-RAM data will be unencrypted, which the VPS host sysadmins would have access to, including the decryption passphrase. If you really have this stringent of security requirements, it sounds like you need to run your own physically-secured systems or find a dedicated server hosting company that specializes in this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [encrypted FUSE](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2007/05/29/encrypting-data-with-the-fuse-encryption-module/) - the only problem being that you need to remount the filesystem when the system reboots. However bear in mind that anyone with access to the VPS image can potentially add bug your code to detect the pass phrase you use.

> Is it possible to secure running processes in memory ?

Not sure what you mean here. It's possible to modify any running process with root access, and also the kernel.

Comment: This would be a private server, and assuming the provider has 99.9% uptime they say they do, rebooting and remounting wouldn't be much of a problem.Since they have physical access, getting root is not a problem, I'm still wondering if FUSE would be sufficient ?

Answer (score -1):

In second question- If i have  vps  with my own root  i cant  access  to   your filesystem. I can  but i need to use ssh  or some remote  solution.

In first question .  If   you have   some clients who using  your vps   you can add him max memory for using.

If i   make some dump  for momery crashing  i will  crash only my memory on vps  , not  your .

Comment: Neither of these answers make any sense with regards to the questions asked.